# Do I need a transit visa

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas

I am travelling from India to Netherlands, and have Schengen visa for Netherlands. While returning from Amsterdam to Delhi,  India I have a flight layover at Frankfurt, Germany around 13.35 hours. Means from Amsterdam to Frankfort I will reach in around 2hours and there I have to wait for around 14hours then change my flight to come to Delhi via muscat.

Do I need a transit visa for changing flights (same